# Regarding secondary growth in dicotyledonous angiosperms

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

[image]

I had read that (and as this image shows) the secondary and primary phloem eventually get crushed due to the repeated division of cells forming the secondary xylem, during secondary growth in dicotyledonous stems. While the primary xylem remains intact, the secondary and primary phloem are crushed.

My question: Is the phloem crushed to such an extent that it is not usable by the plant to conduct organic solutes? Then how does it compensate for this? Does the xylem take over the functions of the phloem?